# PHP get string from a variable and avoid the reference

Tags: php, string, session

I'd first like to mention that I'm not looking for an alternative method. I actually want to try and figure out how to fix this. I am sure a lot of you are familiar with this code:

```
$pageURL = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") 
{
   $pageURL .= "s";
}
   $pageURL .= "://";

if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") 
{
   $pageURL.=_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
else {
   $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
```

This code gets the URL of the current page it's used on. What I want to do is get a string from the URL and put it into a session. I've tried using code such:

```
$_SESSION['pageURL']=$pageURL;

//and

$_SESSION['pageURL']= (string)$pageURL;
```

So far all of my effort have been fruitless, any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Why won't the first example work?  Are you calling `session_start()` at the top of the page?

Comment: You're all actually right, it was a syntax error I made on the second page but I couldn't tell since the URL would've been the same if it didn't work. Thank you all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$pageURL` already is a string, so:

```
$_SESSION['pageURL']=$pageURL;
```

should work without any problems.

Are you using `session_start()` somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

> $_SESSION['pageURL']=$pageURL; //Obviously won't work

That actually works perfectly... Make sure you have called [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)?

Answer (score 1):

session_start();
$_SESSION['pageURL']=$pageURL;